# Why Model is called "Model" in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller

I know the `Model` component of MVC corresponds to all the "data-related logic". If that is true, why it's called "Model" ? why not something else like "Data" or "Entity" or "Table" or "Thing" or whatever more understandable..?

The word "model" as a noun, it can have many meanings, according to the dictionary:

> 1. a three-dimensional representation of a person or thing or of a proposed structure, typically on a smaller scale than the original: a model of St Paul's Cathedral | [as modifier] : a model aeroplane.
> 2. a thing used as an example to follow or imitate: the project became a model for other schemes.
> 3. a simplified description, especially a mathematical one, of a system or process, to assist calculations and predictions: a statistical model used for predicting the survival rates of endangered species.
> 4. a person employed to display clothes by wearing them: Jane was too small to be a model | a well-known fashion model.
> 5. a particular design or version of a product: the company revealed their latest model at the Motor Show.

well, in the context of "MVC", which one does it correspond? and why?

Comment: Hint: Computer Science is a branch of mathematics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a terminology question, not a practical programming problem. Not "liking" or understanding the name selected for something doesn't prevent any program from working.

Answer (score 1):

> (...)  why it's called "Model" ? why not something else like "Data" or
>   "Entity" or "Table" or "Thing" or whatever more understandable

Because, as you mentioned, it also corresponds ***data-related logic***. The Model is not only a data-structure but also manages data and may contain rules and logic to handle data.

> well, in the context of "MVC", which one does it correspond? and why?

Out of the definitions you provided I'd say 3: 
**"a simplified description, especially a mathematical one, of a system or process"** 
MVC is first and foremost not an implementation but an architecture pattern. The "Model" part can also be seen as a description of the domain system. As @Caleth hinted this is mostly a theoretical model, therefore it's independent if the actual implementation or realization.